# With React hooks how to update 2 hooks together, but use prevState of one in other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the code below, when I call `_toggleSearch` I update 2 hooks simultaneously.

`toggleSearchIsVisible` is a simple boolean, however, `setActiveFilter` hook must pass in the previous `searchIsVisible` state.

How can I be sure the other state hasn't updated yet when passed in? Or how else should I restructure everything? Previously with `setState` I could've passed in the previous state easily.

```
const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState('SHOW_ALL');
const [searchIsVisible, toggleSearchIsVisible] = useState(false);

const _toggleSearch = () => {
  setActiveFilter(searchIsVisible ? 'SHOW_SEARCH' : 'SHOW_ALL');
  toggleSearchIsVisible(!searchIsVisible);
};
```

I've gone with this for now:

```
const _toggleSearch = () => {
  if (searchIsActive) {
    setActiveFilter('SHOW_ALL');
    toggleSearchIsActive(false);
  } else {
    setActiveFilter('SHOW_SEARCH');
    toggleSearchIsActive(true);
    updateSearchValue('');
  }
};
```

Any other suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `useEffect` hook to deal with the side effects of toggling the `searchIsVisible` boolean.

Here is an example:

```
const _toggleSearch = () => {
  toggleSearchIsVisible(!searchIsVisible);
};

useEffect(() => {
  setActiveFilter(searchIsVisible ? 'SHOW_ALL' : 'SHOW_SEARCH');
}, [searchIsVisible]);
```

---

You can see that I also passed `[searchIsVisible]` to the `useEffect` hook to optimize performance.

This will ensure that `useEffect` is only triggered when `searchIsVisible` is updated: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

---

Here is a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/l2901jr68l

I hope this helps.

**Note:**

Also I switched the order of `SHOW_ALL` and `SHOW_SEARCH` in your conditional, because it would seem that `SHOW_SEARCH` should be displayed when `searchIsVisible` is `false`, and `SHOW_ALL` should be displayed when `searchIsVisible` is `true`, but if that's not the case just switch the order back.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a situation about syncing two states, take a step back and see if one of the states can be derived from the other. It seems that in this case the two states you have that are essentially related, and one of them can indeed be derived from the other. So you actually don't need two state values, you only need one. Derived state should not be part of state as that leads to duplication of state and then you have to sync up the state values, which is what you are asking in your question.

In the examples below, I demonstrate how you can use either `activeFilter` or `searchIsVisible` as the single state to retain.

If you retain `activeFilter`, the value of `searchIsVisible` is derived from the and vice versa. The key is to set `searchIsVisible` in depending on the value of `activeFilter`.

### `activeFilter` as state

```js
const App = () => {
  const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = React.useState('SHOW_ALL');
  const searchIsVisible = activeFilter !== 'SHOW_ALL';

  const _toggleSearch = () => {
    setActiveFilter(activeFilter === 'SHOW_ALL' ? 'SHOW_SEARCH' : 'SHOW_ALL');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Active Filter: {activeFilter}</p>
      <button onClick={_toggleSearch}>Toggle Search</button>
      {searchIsVisible && <div>
        <input placeholder="Search" />
      </div>}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

### `searchIsVisible` as state

```js
const App = () => {
  const [searchIsVisible, setSearchIsVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const activeFilter = searchIsVisible ? 'SHOW_SEARCH' : 'SHOW_ALL';

  const _toggleSearch = () => {
    setSearchIsVisible(!searchIsVisible);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Active Filter: {activeFilter}</p>
      <button onClick={_toggleSearch}>Toggle Search</button>
      {searchIsVisible && <div>
        <input placeholder="Search" />
      </div>}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```